# Print the results of a grep to a csv file

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to print the results of grep to a CSV file. When I run this command `grep FILENAME *` in my directory I get this result : `B140509184-#-02Jun2015-#-11:00-#-12:00-#-LT4-UGW-MAJAZ-#-I-#-CMAP-#-P-45088966.lif:    FILENAME A20150602.0835+0400-0840+0400_DXB-GGSN-V9-PGP-16.xml`.

What I want is to print the `FILENAME` part to a csv. Below is what I have tried so far, I am a bit lost in the part of how I should go about printing the result

```
BASE_DIR=/appl/virtuo/var/loader/spool/umtsericssonggsn_2013a/2013A/good

cd ${BASE_DIR}

grep FILENAME *
#grep END_TIME *
#grep START_TIME *

#my $Filename = grep FILENAME *;
print $Filename;


#$ awk '{print;}' employee.txt

#echo "$Filename :"
```

File sample

```
measInfoId 140509184
GP 3600
START_DATE 2015-06-02



Output should be 140509184 3600 2015-06-02, in columns of a csv file
```

Comment: Please click `edit` underneath your question and then paste in a few lines of your input file and then afterwards show what the output should look like. Indent all code/data files with 4 spaces at the start of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

If you only want lines that start with `GP`, or `START_DATE` or `measInfoId`, you would modify the `awk` commands below to look like this:

```
awk '/^GP/ || /^START_DATE/ || /^measInfoId/ {print $2}' file
```

**Original Answer**

I am not sure what you are trying to do actually, but this may help...

If your input file is called `file`, and contains this:

```
measInfoId 140509184
GP 3600
START_DATE 2015-06-02
```

This command will print the second field on each line:

```
awk '{print $2}' file
140509184
3600
2015-06-02
```

Then, building on that, this command will put all those onto a single line:

```
awk '{print $2}' file | xargs
140509184 3600 2015-06-02
```

And then this one will translate the spaces into commas:

```
awk '{print $2}' file | xargs | tr " " ","
140509184,3600,2015-06-02
```

And if you want to do that for all the files in a directory, you can do this:

```
for f in *; do
   awk '{print $2}' "$f" | xargs | tr " " ","
done > result.cv
```

Comment: This prints the result for all info in the file, what if I want only certain info, like lets say from the first and third line only ? I only want specific values from the file

Comment: I am still facing an issue, I have more than 1 file in the directory, and it is not possible to include the filename, as the different files will have different names but similar content. How would I go about this, Thank you very much

Comment: Use an asterisk `*` for the filename (in place of `file` that I used) and it will process all the files, but still only generate any output for the ones containing the strings you are looking for, i.e. those containing `START_DATE` or `GP` etc.

Comment: awk '/^GP/ || /^START_DATE/ || /^measInfoId/ {print $2}' * , I tried this but now nothing is returned

Comment: Maybe you have spaces in your input files that you didn't show in front of those strings. Try removing the `^` symbols so `GP` and `START_DATE` don't have to be at the very start of the line.